# How do you preserve the ID field when using the osgeo/ogr/gdal VectorTranslate function in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, export, ogr, osgeo

When using the Python `osgeo`/`gdal`/`ogr` library, how can I force the feature ID column (e.g., "OBJECTID" or "FID" columns) to be preserved in the output file?

I thought I would just need to use the "-preserve_fid" option/flag, but it just doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I've got so far:

```py
# Importing main libraries
import os
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdal

# Use OGR specific exceptions
ogr.UseExceptions()
gdal.UseExceptions() 

# Definitions for input data
inDriverName = "OpenFileGDB"
inGDBPath = 'path/to/input.gdb'
inLayerName = 'input_layer_name'

inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName(inDriverName)
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(inGDBPath, 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayerByName(inLayerName)
inLayerIDColname = inLayer.GetFIDColumn()
inlayerDefinition = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
inLayerColNames = [inlayerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName() for i 
                   in range(inlayerDefinition.GetFieldCount())]]

# Definitions for output data
outCSVPath = 'path/to/output.csv'
outDriverName = 'CSV'

outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName(outDriverName)


# Remove output CSV if it already exists
if os.path.exists(outCSVPath):
    outDriver.DeleteDataSource(outCSVPath)

# Establishing the VectorTranslateOptions
gdoptions=gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(options=['-lco','GEOMETRY=AS_WKT',
                                               '-preserve_fid',],
                                      format=outDriverName,
                                      layers=[inLayerName])

# Executing the VectorTranslate command
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate(destNameOrDestDS=outCSVPath, 
                          srcDS=inGDBPath, 
                          options=gdoptions)

# Releasing the data
ds = None
```

Note that the code above does indeed include the `-preserve_fid` option.

However, when I use this script to export a specific layer inside a GDB, the FIDs are not included in the newly-generated CSV file.

Is there anything missing in my input above?

Comment: Try setting a SELECT SQLStatement that is explicit about the FID column, something like "select fid, blah, blah from db". Or try the selectFields option?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sadly though, that doesn't seem to work. When I add `selectFields=[inLayer.GetFIDColumn(), *[inlayerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName() for i in range(inlayerDefinition.GetFieldCount())]]` in the `VectorTranslateOptions`, that stops the main `VectorTranslate` command from working. It seems that the `selectFields` option only works for non-FID fields. Note: the complicated field selection command just gets all the column names including the FID column name.

Comment: I am not sure if FID is translated into CSV with -preserve_fid. For a comparison try what happens with GeoPackage. Using SQL `"select fid_column as fid, attr_1, attr_2..." should work. Try with both with the default OGR and SQLite SQL dialect.

Comment: @user30184: Thank you!!! After a few attempts, your idea worked. Here are the extra keywords needed in the `VectorTranslateOptions` element: `SQLStatement=f'select {inLayerIDColname} as {inLayerIDColname}, * from {inLayerName}', SQLDialect='OGRSQL'`. If you want to post it as an actual answer, I'd be happy to upvote it and mark it as the official answer.

Comment: Please write the answer yourself because you are more in with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a special SQLStatement keyword in the VectorTranslateOptions:

```py
gdoptions=gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(options=['-lco','GEOMETRY=AS_WKT',
                                               '-preserve_fid',],
                                      format=outDriverName,
                                      SQLStatement=f'select {inLayerIDColname} as {inLayerIDColname}, * from {inLayerName}',
                                      SQLDialect='OGRSQL',
                                      layers=[inLayerName])
```